# Как сделать так чтобы потоки работали по очереди синхронно

Tags: java, многопоточность

хотел бы знать как сделать так чтобы с начало выполнялся 1 поток , и только после 2 и так по кругу, на этом примере.

```
class SomeThread implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run(){
    for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " Number: " + i);
    }
}}

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new SomeThread());
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new SomeThread());

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}}
```

Т.е если запустить этот код, то выводимые цифры буду вперемешку

```
Thread-0 Number: 0
Thread-0 Number: 1
Thread-1 Number: 0
Thread-0 Number: 2
Thread-0 Number: 3
Thread-1 Number: 1
Thread-1 Number: 2
Thread-0 Number: 4
Thread-0 Number: 5
Thread-1 Number: 3
Thread-1 Number: 4
Thread-0 Number: 6
.....
```

А нужно чтобы с начало выводилось 0-0, потом 1-1,2-2 и т.д.
Пробовал использовать synchronize

```
public final static Object lock = new Object();
@Override
public  void run(){
   synchronized (lock) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Number: " + i);
       }
   }
}
```

Но с начала выводятся результаты одного потока и только после результаты другого потока.

```
Thread-0 Number: 0
Thread-0 Number: 1
Thread-0 Number: 2
Thread-0 Number: 3
Thread-0 Number: 4
Thread-0 Number: 5
Thread-0 Number: 6
Thread-0 Number: 7
Thread-0 Number: 8
Thread-0 Number: 9
Thread-1 Number: 0
Thread-1 Number: 1
Thread-1 Number: 2
Thread-1 Number: 3
....
```

Нужно чтобы выводился по одному числу на каждой итерации от потока, сначала первый поток выведет число, потом второй , опять первый и опять второй и так до конца цикла. Вывод должен быть такой:

```
Thread-0 Number: 0
Thread-1 Number: 0
Thread-0 Number: 1
Thread-1 Number: 1 
Thread-0 Number: 2
Thread-1 Number: 2
Thread-0 Number: 3
Thread-1 Number: 3
…..
```

То есть числа не должны быть вперемешку, если я не ошибаюсь  это называется "Состояние гонки"

Comment: Это тебе на каждую итерацию нужен новый поток?
Какой должен быть конечный вывод? Немного не понятно, что тебе нужно..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для управления очерёдностью потоков можно использовать некое абстрактное id потока (которым может быть как его имя так и произвольно присвоенное id) и вести мониторинг id, данные которого необходимо отображать. Постановку потоков на ожидание, если их id не совпадает с необходимым, удобнее делать с помощью синхронизаторов (например `ReentrantLock`), либо используя методы блокировки монитора класса `Object`. Приведу пример для второго варианта:

```
public class SomeThread implements Runnable {
    private final static Object lock = new Object();
    private static int numOfThreads;
    private static int currentThreadId;
    private final int threadId;

    public SomeThread() {
        threadId = numOfThreads++;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i =0; i<10; i++) {

            synchronized (lock) {
                while (currentThreadId != threadId) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Number: " + i);
                currentThreadId = threadId == numOfThreads - 1 ? 0 : threadId + 1;
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для числа потоков больше 2х этот код корректный, но не эффективный, потому что будет будить все потоки - и тот который должен отработать следующим, и те, которые не должны.

Comment: Я бы вообще сказал, что наличие в коде `notifyAll` / `signalAll` - это повод внимательно присмотреться к коду.

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать через очереди через которые потоки будут передавать друг другу "эстафету". Например такой поток:

```java
class MyThread extends Thread{

    BlockingQueue<String> in;
    BlockingQueue<String> out;

    public MyThread(BlockingQueue<String> in, BlockingQueue<String> out){
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            try {
                in.take();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Number: " + i);
                out.put("your turn");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А вызвать код можно так:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    BlockingQueue<String> t1t2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1);
    BlockingQueue<String> t2t1 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1);
    new MyThread(t1t2, t2t1).start();
    new MyThread(t2t1, t1t2).start();
    t1t2.put("Start");
}
```